# How do I use Sessions in windows form application VB.net?

Tags: vb.net-2010

I have tried storing log in ID in a variable after the user logs into the system and then use it get the users information. I think its not a good programming practice and would like to have a better alternative. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData (varname)
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData(varname)